# How to exit login screen and start commandline while at login screen

Tags: linux, command-line, console

I am at the gnome 2 login screen but I want to exit and re-enter command-line environment.  I remember there was a combination hot key one has to invoke.

Comment: On which operative system are you?

Answer (score 32):

Are you looking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> ?

This will switch to the first virtual console. Usually several virtual consoles are available from <kbd>F1</kbd> up to <kbd>F6</kbd>. The 7th is usually the one used by the login screen, so you can switch back using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> (or whatever is the relevant one).

Comment: on my ubuntu 20, f1 seems to belong to the login screen, so nothing happened when i pressed ctrl+alt+f1, ctrl+alt+f2 worked in my case

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> (there are also terminals on the following F-keys, for me up to <kbd>F6</kbd>).

To get back to the GUI, use <kbd>F7</kbd> instead.

Comment: I actually tried that - I know what the problem is now.  For some reason my keyboard is not active at the login screen...

Comment: **"there are also terminals on the following F-keys"** thank you, my fedora 28 is F3